# Converting Double to String in C++

Tags: c++, string, double

I am having some issues trying to convert a double to C++ string. Here is my code

```
std::string doubleToString(double val)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << val;
    return out.str();
}
```

The problem I have is if a double is being passed in as '10000000'. Then the string value being returned is 1e+007

How can i get the string value as "10000000"

Comment: How about some of the examples from the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx   They are very efficient and somewhat elegant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
// ...
out << fixed << val;
// ...
```

You might also consider using `setprecision` to set the number of decimal digits:

```
out << fixed << setprecision(2) << val;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <iomanip>

std::string doubleToString(double val)
{
   std::ostringstream out;
   out << std::fixed << val;
   return out.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the minimum width and fill char with STL IO manipulators, like:

```
out.width( 9 );
out.fill( ' ' );
```