# convert float to string

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert double to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123201/convert-double-to-string-c)

I searched in the page but i haven't found the solution.

I have a method to convert from int to string. But now i need to convert from float/double to string. Because i want to write some data in a file.

Anyone could help me ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By string you mean C++ string or char *?

Comment: I've done some basic stuff in C, and I think something like char incy = (char *) bincy; I might be completely wrong, though. :)

Comment: Why would writing data to a file require conversion to string?

Comment: How about `fprintf(outFile, "%f\n", floatVar);` ?

Comment: I need a conversion before print/write the variable. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29200635/395461

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/146718

```
#include <sstream>
std::string Convert (float number){
    std::ostringstream buff;
    buff<<number;
    return buff.str();   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/).

You could use [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) with << operator.

See also [Convert double to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123201/convert-double-to-string-c), [How do I convert a double into a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332111/how-do-i-convert-a-double-into-a-string-in-c), [Convert double to string using boost::lexical_cast in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016464/boostlexical-cast-conversion-double-to-string-c), [Converting Double to String in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864250/converting-double-to-string-in-c), etc.

Answer (score 4):

Can you not use the standard (C) function sprintf/fprintf etc?

Comment: No i need a conversion before writing the file.

Comment: sprintf allows you to "convert" (format really) into a string (char *) -- which you then can write to file or do with it as you please really.

Comment: Note that windows until recently did not support the same snprintf commands that linux does, and they don't work in the same way. This caused portability issues with code. As of the latest Visual Studio Microsoft's implementation of snprintf is standards compliant.

Answer (score 3):

This can help you : [Convert double to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123201/convert-double-to-string-c/1123216#1123216)

Answer (score 2):

Is your file written using IOStreams? If so, just do this:

```
stream << number;
```

If not, and you really need a string, you can use an `ostringstream` for this. Boost's `lexical_cast` wraps the string streams in an easy-to-use fashion.