# Control the Precision of float number in a string - C++

Tags: c++, string, floating-point, precision

I'm trying to control the number of Digits i add in a String , but I couldn't control it since i am printing an Array of Strings .

```
float loads[n] = { 1,2,3,0.05,1,2,3,0.5,1,2,3,3,1,2 };
string print[nBits] = { "" };
int n=14;
int BB;
.
.
.
void main(){
 for (int j = 0; j < nBits; ++j)// 2^n
   {     
         for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) // n
        {
            BB = arr[j][i];
            R = loads[i];
            if (BB == 1) {
            print[j]+="" +std::to_string(loads[i])+"//";
        }
   }
}
```

But i eventually get an Array of strings that Looks like this :

> 0.050000//3.000000//...

Is there any way to control the Precision of the floating number before adding it to the String ?

(so i can have a resulting string control a fixed number of Digits instead)

> 0.05//3.00// ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert float to string with set precision & number of decimal digits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200635/convert-float-to-string-with-set-precision-number-of-decimal-digits)

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::stringstream` together with `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision(n)`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard streaming mechanic:

### streams

You can use ostream to generate the string:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostringstream stream;
for(...) {
   stream << loads[i] << "//";
}
std::string str =  stream.str();
```

The idea is to generate a stream that you can stream strings too. You can then generate a `std::string` out of it, using `stream.str()`. Streams have default values for how to convert numbers. You can influence this with `std::setprecision` and `std::fixed` as well as other variables (for more info, see the [C++ stdlib reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)).

Using `std::setprecision` and `std::fixed`.

```
std::ostringstream stream;
// set the precision of the stream to 2 and say we want fixed decimals, not
// scientific or other representations.
stream << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;

for(...) {
   stream << loads[i] << "//";
}
std::string str =  stream.str();
```

You find another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29200635/convert-float-to-string-with-set-precision-number-of-decimal-digits).

### sprintf

You can always go the C way and use `sprintf` although it's discouraged as you have to provide a buffer of correct length, e.g.:

```
char buf[50];
if (snprintf(buf, 50, "%.2f", loads[i]) > 0) {
   std::string s(buf);
}
```